# How can I decode the inputs to a transaction written by a smart contract constructor with Nethereum?

Tags: abi, nethereum

I've been able to decode the inputs to a contract *function* transaction given the ABI as follows:

```cs
var myFunction = contract.GetFunction("MyFunction");
var myFunctionTxn = await contract.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionByHash
        .SendRequestAsync(myTxnHash);
var inputs = myFunction.DecodeInput(myFunctionTxn.Input);
```

However, now I would like to do the same (i.e. retrieve a transaction hash and then decode the constructor inputs) for the *constructor* itself. I've looked at the `ContractABI.Functions` - I can see both the Constructor and the Functions, but the types are not compatable.

Also, I can see the types of the inputs from this, but unfortunately not the values:

```cs
var ctor = contract.ContractBuilder.ContractABI.Constructor;
```

Is there an equivalent for `DecodeInput` for constructors?

From here, it looks like this [must be possible](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.ABI/FunctionEncoding/ConstructorCallDecoder.cs)

Comment: if you have the ABI of this contract, this must be possible just the same way as decoding input of any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a brief [conversation on Gitter](https://gitter.im/Nethereum/Nethereum?at=5b80f543ac25fd11b58fe23d) with Nethereum's [Juan Blanco](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/573/juan-blanco), I'm using the code from the [ConstructorCallDecoder](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.ABI/FunctionEncoding/ConstructorCallDecoder.cs) to decode the Constructor.

```
using Nethereum.Web3;
...
var contract = _ethClient.Eth.GetContract(_contractAbi, contractAddress);
var ctorTransaction = await contract.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionByHash
    .SendRequestAsync(constructorTransactionHash);
var decodedCtor = new ConstructorCallDecoder()
    .DecodeConstructorParameters(
        pocoToPopulate, _contractByteCode, ctorTransaction.Input);
```

Where

- `_contractAbi` is the ABI for the smart contract
- `contractAddress` is the address of the contract instance
- `constructorTransactionHash` is the transaction hash of the constructor
- `_contractByteCode` is the byte code of the Smart Contract
- `pocoToPopulate` is an instance of a class decorated with the necessary [Parameter attributes](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts/functiondtos/) to receive the decoded parameters.

There are likely simpler ways to do this in future (e.g. without the redundancy of requiring both ABI and ByteCode to do the decoding), but this is good enough for me right now.

Comment: Hello StuartLC, your revert here did give me hope but i am getting below error using this method : System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.............. By anychance do you have any code repo which i can use for reference.

Comment: @logeekal those kinds of errors usually result from not matching the provided ABI, and bytecode to the same version that was used to actually write at the contract address. It might also mean that your contract address or transaction hash don't add up. In the above we're using the constructor but this should work for any transaction on the contract